# If i want to find how similar two independent vectors are. Should i find their dot product? Or their angle? Or their distance (metric space)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think that i understand on a tolerable level what the terms on the title are, but i cant figure out their difference on a practical level. For example lets say that i have v = [0,1,1,0,1], u = [1,1,0,2,0] and z = [1,0,1,0,1]. And i want to find which is most closely related to w = [0,1,0,1,1].
What do i do?

1. Find the dot product of each one of the v,u,z with the vector w, and the vector whose dot product with w has the highest value is the most closely related
2. Find the different cosines of v,u,z with w, and the largest cosine (meaning smallest angle) will show the the vector that is most closely related
3. Find the distance between v,u,z with w, and the smallest distance will show us the answer

I simply cant see the difference between these 3 things, so if you provide some intuition it would help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

These three notions are all related by the dot (inner) product.

1. The dot product $v \cdot w$ is affected by both the lengths of $v$ and $w$ as well as by the angle between them, as can be seen from the formula $v \cdot w = \|v\| \|w\| \cos(\theta)$, where $\|v\|$ and $\|w\|$ are the lengths of $v$ and $w$, and $\theta$ is the angle between them.
2. You can get just the angle from the dot product. Since $v \cdot w = \|v\|\|w\|\cos(\theta)$, solving for $\theta$ gives $\displaystyle \theta = \arccos\left(\frac{v \cdot w}{\|v\|\|w\|}\right)$. Note that $\|v\|$ and $\|w\|$ themselves can be computed via dot products, namely $\|v\| = \sqrt{v \cdot v}$ and $\|w\| = \sqrt{w \cdot w}$.
3. The Euclidean distance between $v$ and $w$, i.e. $\|v - w\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(v_i - w_i)^2}$ where $n$ is the dimension of the vectors, can also be obtained from the dot product. To see this, to compute the square of the distance:

$$\begin{aligned}
\|v - w\|^2 = (v - w) \cdot (v - w) = v\cdot v + 2 v \cdot w + w \cdot w\\
\end{aligned}$$

and therefore
$$\|v - w\| = \sqrt{v\cdot v + 2 v \cdot w + w \cdot w}$$

Note that this can also be written as
$$\|v - w\| = \sqrt{\|v\|^2 + 2\|v\|\|w\|\cos(\theta) + \|w\|^2},$$
which shows that the Euclidean distance is a function of both the lengths of $v$ and $w$ and of the angle between them.

---

Which of these to use in a given situation is entirely dependent on what you want to measure.

A general remark is that $v \cdot w$ itself is not a great way to determine which vector $w$ is closest to $v$. To see why, look again at the formula $v \cdot w = \|v\|\|w\|\cos(\theta)$. For a fixed $v$, this formula can be made larger either by making $\|w\|$ larger or by making $\theta$ closer to $0$ (so $v$ and $w$ are closer to parallel). In particular, a large value of $v \cdot w$ could result from a $w$ with a large length even if it isn't pointing anywhere near the same direction as $v$.

If you care only about the angle between the vectors, then choose the normalized dot product $\displaystyle \frac{v \cdot w}{\|v\|\|w\|}$ (which is $\cos(\theta)$), or the arccosine of the normalized dot product (which is $\theta)$. This will completely disregard the lengths of $v$ and $w$, so for example $v = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]$ and $w = [1000, 0, 0, 0, 0]$ will have zero angle even though the lengths are very different.

If you care about both the angle and the lengths, then it generally makes sense to use $\|v - w\|$.

Comment: I see, thank you!